# Unable to integrate SSRS 2008 with MySQL

Tags: mysql, reporting-services

I would really appreciate any help for this problem.

Basically I am using SSRS 2008 for reporting services. My choice of DB was MySQL. So I installed ODBC MySQL connector and created a DSN and used it in report design. If I preview the report in the Business Intelligence Dev Studio, I can see the records, but when I try to view in the local URL:

```
http://mycomputername:port/Reports
```

it says:

> DataSource1 not found or driver not installed.

Can anyone please tell me if this is a problem with SSRS configurations or do I need to make any changes to make it work in a URL-based scheme?

Answer (score 0):

Any custom data source should be present in the *rsreportserver.config* file located in

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSRS10.SQLEXPRESS\Reporting
>   Services\ReportServer

(Your location will be different depending on SQL Server version /installed  path etc.)

More specifically in the < Data > section. I would be surprised if the MySQL ODBC connector would facilitate this.

If it works in the designer, you would probably have a line in the *RSReportDesigner.config* file located in

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio
>   9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies

Copy that < Data > line and put it in the *rsreportserver.config* file.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than ODBC you can install Mysql Connector for .Net ,Download and install the connector after installing the connector open the Report Server Url ,click new data source ,select data source as "MYSQL" on Connection string type the following

```
SERVER=mysqlserver;DATABASE=database name;USER=username;PASSWORD=password;
```

Comment: After I downloaded the connector from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=463758. I still unable to see the Data Source "MYSQL". Is there anything that I missed?